# Does HttpSessionListener have any drawback?

Tags: spring-mvc, listener, session-timeout

I have a web application where I need to delete 1 record from the database when there is a session timeout.
To implement this I have implemented the HttpSessionListener Interface.And the record gets deleted in the
sessionDestroyed method.
I want to know is this the right way?(Accessing the database in sessionDestroyed method) OR is there any other way?
Also I want to know whether this will create any overhead on the existing application in terms of performance / memory?

Thanks in advance!